# Ionic2 auto updating data

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am building Mobile application using ionic2. it has two logins. one login for students and other login for Teachers. students can request topics to teacher .how can i auto update count to teachers login without refreshing screen when student requests topic.? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Provide an [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase for backend. It supports event based data retrieval.